# Move file in Python with shutil that has just been changed

Tags: python, file, subprocess, shutil

I wrote a Python script which calls subprocess which will create a file:

```
subprocess.run(["youtube-dl.exe", "-o " + fileName, link])
```

After that I'd like to move my file to a different directory:

```
shutil.copy("C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\m2.m4a", "C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\Songs\\m2.m4a")
```

But that gives me the following error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\***\Desktop\m2.m4a'
But the file definitely exists. I tried to move a file which has not just been altered, and it works. 
In case Windows needs time to create the file properly, I paused the code after the file creation and before the shutil.move-command:

```
time.sleep(4)
```

But it still doesn't work. Is it maybe because subprocess is still running and shutil can't access the file at  the same time? Or because Python doesn't know that a new file has just been created? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `-o` should be its own argument, although that may not matter on Windows.